# How do I get Parity client to connect to Peers?

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, ethereumj, parity-wallet

I'd like to use the Advanced Send feature on Parity but am having issues connecting to Peers. For example, it says on the lower bottom right, 0/15/20 peers. The first number is always 0. I do not know if this is the cause of the problem but I figured it would be a start.

When I schedule a transaction at a certain block, it gets stuck on the last step. After closing the dialog since it doesn't go anywhere, I go over to TxQueue Viewer and the transaction is there on the list. However, it doesn't move beyond the status: "First propagation: Never".

Is there a way to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: You have 15 connections, that's perfectly fine.

Comment: Regarding your 2nd question: The blockchain is full, it might take a few hours to get your transaction mined.